# Why am I getting a SQL71502 unresolved warning with master database reference

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-data-tools, windows-11

I'm getting a SQL71502 has an unresolved reference to object even though I've included the master database. Even after rebuilding the solution. I've also closed Visual Studio, removed the bin and obj directory and removed the `.dbmdl` and `.jfm` files.

The warning appears on this SQL statement:

```
SELECT current_utc_offset 
FROM sys.time_zone_info 
WHERE name = 'UTC';
```

This is an Azure SQL database and the above select statement works when running from SSMS.

This is also popping up as an error during my CI/CD pipeline with the following error:

> Error SQL72033: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because [dbo].[ProcName] depends on [sys].[time_zone_info].[name] and [sys].[time_zone_info].[name] does not exist in the target database.

But it does exist in the target database. I figure if I can get the Visual Studio build to work without issuing a warning then I'll be able to fix the CI/CD pipeline error.

Comment: Answer to this question was provided on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1234048/why-am-i-getting-a-sql71502-unresolved-warning-wit

Comment: FYI - I don't exactly know when, but Microsoft fixed this issue in Visual Studio. I do know it was fixed after version 17.5.0

Answer (score 0):

As @Boris Von dahle said some of the system objects are not recognized by SSDT, it may be the reason for above error. System objects are available at run time because of that those are not recognized by SSDT. for that need to create new system object for **`sys.time_zone_info`** .
1.Create a new folder in project named "SystemObjects".

2.Add table named "time_zone_info.sql" to the folder.

[image]

3.Replace below script in the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [sys].[time_zone_info]
    (
        [name] sysname NOT NULL,
        [current_utc_offset] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
        [is_currently_dst] bit NOT NULL
    )
```

Add below line at beginning of pre-deployment script:

```
:setvar TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings true
DROP TABLE [sys].[time_zone_info];
```

In this way you may resolve the issue. For information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1234048/why-am-i-getting-a-sql71502-unresolved-warning-wit).